# ImageButton difference between setBackground and setImageResource and setImageDrawable

Tags: android

What is the difference between `android:setBackground` & `android:setImageResource` when used with an `ImageView`

I was trying to change the icon of imageButton onclick. when I used:

```
flashBTN.setImageResource(R.drawable.torch_icon_grey);
```

I am getting the button covered in grey and the correct drawable doesn't show.
And when I am trying :

```
flashBTN.setBackground(R.drawable.torch_icon_grey);
```

I am getting `error:setBackground ca't be applied to int`

Bonus: How `setImageDrawable` is difference?

Answer (score 0):

you can read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). I think you are talking about this in xml:

`android:background` -> A drawable to use as the background, it could be just a color in HEX notation or a drawable.

`android:src` -> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

However in java you can use `setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)` for setting a drawable as the content of this ImageView.